# Is it good to create ThreadPoolExecutor bean and inject it in spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, threadpool

I'm creating a `ThreaPoolExecutor` in a spring bean at instance level for executing stuff concurrently, but my fellow developer suggested that I should create its bean and inject it wherever required which obviously is a clearer way.

I was thinking another way around i.e. the class should have the responsibility to create/manage resources it created, also there are chances that other developers may inject it (`ThreadPoolExecutor`) some other bean and accidentally shut it down and thus hamper other beans (using `ThreadPoolExecutor`) as well. 
Please suggest what should be the best approach to handle such scenario.

Comment: Shut down your thread pool? If that happens you can get to know while testing . If you never want to shut down that threadpoolexecutor why not simply override shutdown method while bean creation.

Comment: @Rakesh Yeah that could be a solution, but what about creating and managing resources in same class?

Comment: Threadpoolexecutor does all those things already If it is not related to thread managing why to put it there? Or did threadpoolexecutor did not provide anything that you are expecting

Comment: No, I get everything what I need from threadPoolExecutor, it's just the way I'm managing it's instance i.e. at class instance level or I can do anything to handle it better